# How to web scrape MLB batting order to excel?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am scraping baseball lineups and importing the python code into excel using pandas.

What I am looking for:

1. Remove quotation marks from names
2. Remove brackets from start and end of each team
3. Split names into different cells

***Example of current output for Team 1:***

```
['Daniel Norris', 'Masahiro Tanaka', 'Mikie Mahtook', etc.]
```

All of the above names have quotation marks, commas, and brackets attached to them. They are all listed in the same cell, too.

***Example of preferred excel output for Team 1:***

```
Daniel Norris    Masahiro Tanaka    Miki Mahtook    etc.
```

As you can see above I would like all of the quotation marks, commas and brackets removed. Also, I would like all of the players names from each team to be in their own respective cells.

I have been looking for the right code online. So far I have seen three examples on stackoverflow.com but they look different than mine. I will show all three. Perhaps one of these can be used in this case.

Example 1 using string method:

```
s = s.strip(['o','1'])
```

Example 2 using replace method:

```
s = s.replace("World", "")
```

Example 3 using remove method:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,2,2,3]
def remove_values_from_list(the_list, val):
    for i in range(the_list.count(val)):
        the_list.remove(val)

remove_values_from_list(x, 2)

print(x)
```

Is it possible to implement one of these codes to do the three items I listed above? If not, perhaps someone can offer me some insight on how to better achieve my goals. I have seen some people online suggest a regex filter. I am not aware of how to use those, though. Thanks in advance for your time and effort!

By the way, I am brand new to coding and scraping. I am very thankful for any help that I may receive. Please let me know if you have any questions or if I can add more detail to better assist you.

Here is my code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.baseballpress.com/lineups'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

all_games = []

for g in soup.find_all(class_="game"):
    players = g.find_all('a', class_='player-link')
    game = {
        'players': [_.text for _ in g.find_all('a', class_='player-link')],
    }
    all_games.append(game)

print(all_games) 

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(all_games)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('batting lineup.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, 'baseball_sheet')
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to scrape to excel I would recommend to use CSV files (instead of the XLSX ones). They are much more easy to manage and generate and to do so, you can use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html) built-in module.

Here is a revisited sample of your code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

url = 'http://www.baseballpress.com/lineups'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

all_games = []

for g in soup.find_all(class_="game"):
    players = g.find_all('a', class_='player-link')
    game = [_.text for _ in g.find_all('a', class_='player-link')]
    all_games.append(game)

with open('players.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    player_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    player_writer.writerows(all_games)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info @LorenzoPersichetti! I will look into this. =)

Comment: This code works great @LorenzoPersichetti! I really appreciate you taking the time to suggest using a csv instead; that was much easier! I have one more question if you don't mind... I have an existing excel file with formulas. I would love to use this code to update one sheet in my file. It seems this code will create a new file each time. Do you have any suggestions on how I can adjust this code to update one sheet in an existing file?